# Floating-point exceptions in multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, x86, floating-point-exceptions

Does the floating point status word work on a per-thread or per-process basis?

I have a program, compiled for x86 32-bit, which at several points in the code calls

```
_status87()
```

at several points in the code. I am trying to figure out whether this could cause problems when multi-threading the application. I found some information saying that the fp control word works on a per-thread basis [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee418872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but have not been able to find anything on the fp status word. I am concerned that fp exceptions might appear in the 'wrong' thread if the fp status word was not on a per-thread basis.

Comment: What OS is your code running in?